# HTML5/Javascript/jQuery audio player isn't responding to events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, media-player

I am trying to make a html5 player with a playlist so that when a song ends the next one begins automatically.

Im using jQuery.

This is my Javascript:

```
$(function(){   
var player = $('#player')
var index = 0
var CurrentTime = 0
var tracks = [  {'source' : 'audio1.mp3'},
                {'source' : 'audio2.mp3'},
                {'source' : 'audio3.mp3'}]

var CurrentTrack = tracks[index]

    function updateCookie(){
        Cookies.set('trackIndex', index)
        Cookies.set('time', CurrentTime)
    }

    //Check if the user has been here before
    if(!!Cookies.get('trackIndex')){
        updateCookie()
    }
    else {
        index = Cookies.get('trackIndex')
        CurrentTime = Cookies.get('time')
    }
    function playerSetUp(){
        player[0].currentSrc = CurrentTrack.source
        player[0].currentTime = CurrentTime
    }


    player.bind('ended',function(){
        index++
        player[0].currentSrc = CurrentTrack.source
        console.log($('#player').currentSrc)
        player[0].load()
        player[0].play()
    })
    player.bind('pause',function(){
        CurrentTime = $('#player').currentTime
        updateCookie()
    })
})
```

And this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mixtape</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-
3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<audio controls autoplay id='player'>
    <source src="audio1.mp3">
    Fallback
</audio>
</body>
```

I want to create a player that imitates the behavior of an analog audio tape. I want it to play one song after the other and when you close the page and open it again the player will continue from the last track and time you paused it.

The problem is my code above doesn't respond to the events.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have three errors in your code, the event listeners are working.
Use:

```
//Check if the user has been here before
if(!Cookies.get('trackIndex')){
    updateCookie()
    CurrentTrack = tracks[index]
}
else {
    index = Cookies.get('trackIndex')
    CurrentTime = Cookies.get('time')
    CurrentTrack = tracks[index]
}
```

(Just one "!"). And you need to update "CurrentTrack" each time you modify your "index", because you just set currentTrack one time.

And:

```
playerSetUp();
player.bind('ended', function() {
    index++;
    index = index % tracks.length
    CurrentTrack = tracks[index]
    player[0].currentSrc = CurrentTrack.source
    console.log(player[0].currentSrc)
    player[0].load()
    player[0].play()
})
player.bind('pause', function() {
    CurrentTime = player[0].currentTime
    updateCookie()
})
```

You need to call playerSetUp() and index = index % tracks.length so that your index wont be bigger than your tracks array.

One more thing: `player[0].currentSrc` is readonly. You need to use `player[0].src`.